# Getting the authenticated user, authed by Apache Basic Auth under Mono and ServiceStack

Tags: c#, apache, rest, mono, servicestack

I'm running a Rest-Service using ServiceStack under Apache2 in C#/Mono. The Apache-Server is using SSL and BasicAuthentication with a htpasswd-file.

If I access my Rest-Service I get the auth-Request of the apache which is good. After authenticating my RestService is accessed. Now my question is: How am I able to get the user (the apache-session user) which has requested the service and authenticated to it?
I allready tried to get the Environment-Variables but didn't get the requested Information there.

The built in Authentication of ServiceStack requires me, as I understand, to implement authentication on my own. But I want to use the authentication of the apache.

Does anyone know a sollution?

Greetings
daily

P.S.
Below are the Mono and SSL relevant Sections of my Site-config for apache:

```
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
   SSLOptions StrictRequire +StdEnvVars
   SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

   MonoServerPath wcs.service.de "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"
   MonoDebug wcs.service.de true
   MonoSetEnv wcs.service.de  MONO_IOMAP=all
   MonoAutoApplication  disabled
   MonoApplications wcs.service.de "/:/var/www/wcs"
```

Comment: I found a solution! It consists of the ServiceStack RequestFilter, the original ASP.net Request and the Param "REMOTE_USER". Will post a more detailed solution tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit later than pronounced, but here is the answer to the question.

In your ServiceStack Service you get your RequestDTO as parameter. See this link:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Access-HTTP-specific-features-in-services

Under the point Services you can see what I mean. You don't need the RequestFilter as I suggested in my answer above. However.. you have this IHttpRequest of Servicestack. On this object you can get the OriginalRequest. This is the original ASP.net-Request. You have to cast the Result to HttpRequest (ASP.net).

```
var orgRequest = (HttpRequest)request.OriginalRequest;
```

On this newly casted object you have an accessable field Param. You can now get the REMOTE_USER param which contains the SSL-User I needed.

```
var sslUser = orgRequest.Param["REMOTE_USER"];
```

I hope this may help someone running into the same problem.

Greetings, daily